# Hugo Academic - Talk Widget appears in separate page, not in home

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown, hugo

I have successfully added the `Talks` menu on the menu bar, however the widget is not showing at the anchored place in the homepage. Instead, it seems to be showing at `[ROOT]/talk`. What did I do wrong?

**Website**: https://maurocamaraescudero.netlify.app/ 
**Code**: https://github.com/MauroCE/PersonalWebsite

## Additional Information

1. Under `[ROOT]/config/_default/menus.toml` I have added the following so that the menu links to the anchor `#talk`.

   ```
   [[main]]
     name = "Talks"
     url = "#talk"
     weight = 25
   ```
2. Under `[ROOT]/layouts/widgets` I have put the file `talk.html`. This is a copy-and-paste from `[ROOT]/themes/academic/layouts/talk/single.html`.

```
{{- define "main" -}}

<div class="pub">

  {{ partial "page_header.html" . }}

  <div class="article-container">

    {{ if .Params.abstract }}
      <h3>{{ i18n "abstract" }}</h3>
      <p class="pub-abstract">{{ .Params.abstract | markdownify | emojify }}</p>
    {{ else }}
      <br>
    {{ end }}

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-3 pub-row-heading">{{ i18n "date" }}</div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
            {{ partial "functions/get_event_dates" . }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-md-none space-below"></div>

    {{ if .Params.event }}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-3 pub-row-heading">{{ i18n "event" }}</div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
            {{ with .Params.event_url }}<a href="{{ . }}" target="_blank" rel="noopener">{{ end }}
            {{ .Params.event | markdownify }}
            {{ if .Params.event_url }}</a>{{ end }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-md-none space-below"></div>
    {{ end }}

    {{ if .Params.location }}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 col-md-3 pub-row-heading">{{ i18n "location" }}</div>
          <div class="col-12 col-md-9">{{ .Params.location | markdownify }}</div>
          {{ if .Params.address }}
            <div class="col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-9">{{partial "functions/get_address" (dict "root" . "address" .Params.address) }}</div>
          {{end}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-md-none space-below"></div>
    {{ end }}

    <div class="space-below"></div>

    <div class="article-style">
      {{ .Content }}
    </div>

    {{ partial "page_footer" . }}

  </div>
</div>
{{- end -}}
```

3. Under `[ROOT]/content/talk/BayesComp2023` I have added an image `featured.jpg` and a file `index.md` with the following heading

```
---
title: My title
event: BayesComp 2023
event_url: https://bayescomp2023.com

location: Levi, Finland

summary: Summary title
abstract: "Abstract"

# Talk start and end times.
date: "2023-03-15T09:00:00Z"
date_end: "2023-03-17T17:00:00Z"
all_day: false

# Schedule page publish date (NOT talk date).
publishDate: "2017-01-01T00:00:00Z"

authors: []
tags: []

# Is this a featured talk? (true/false)
featured: true

image:
 caption: 'Example of a Filamentary Distribution'
 focal_point: Right

links:
- icon: twitter
 icon_pack: fab
 name: Follow
 url: https://twitter.com/
url_code: ""
url_pdf: ""
url_slides: "BayesComp2023_slides.pdf"
url_video: ""

# Enable math on this page?
math: true
---
```

4. Under `[ROOT]/content/home` I have added `talk.md`

```
+++
# Recent and Upcoming Talks widget.
widget = "talk"
active = true
date = "2016-04-20T00:00:00"

title = "Invited Talks"
subtitle = "Subtitle to the talks"

# Order that this section will appear in.
weight = 25

# Number of talks to list.
count = 10

# List format.
#   0 = Simple
#   1 = Detailed
list_format = 0

+++
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it, I think. There's no need to create a new partial. One should delete `talk.html` from `[ROOT]/layouts/partials/widgets` and instead one shouls simply write the following in `talk.md` in `[ROOT]/content/home/talk/md`:

```
+++
widget = "pages"  # See https://sourcethemes.com/academic/docs/page-builder/
headless = true  # This file represents a page section.
active = true  # Activate this widget? true/false
weight = 25  # Order that this section will appear.

title = "A title"
subtitle = "A subtitle"

[content]
  # Page type to display. E.g. post, talk, or publication.
  page_type = "talk"
  
  # Choose how much pages you would like to display (0 = all pages)
  count = 5
  
  # Choose how many pages you would like to offset by
  offset = 0

  # Page order. Descending (desc) or ascending (asc) date.
  order = "desc"

  # Filter posts by a taxonomy term.
  [content.filters]
    tag = ""
    category = ""
    publication_type = ""
    exclude_featured = false
  
[design]
  # Toggle between the various page layout types.
  #   1 = List
  #   2 = Compact
  #   3 = Card
  #   4 = Citation (publication only)
  view = 2
  
[design.background]
  # Apply a background color, gradient, or image.
  #   Uncomment (by removing `#`) an option to apply it.
  #   Choose a light or dark text color by setting `text_color_light`.
  #   Any HTML color name or Hex value is valid.
  
  # Background color.
  # color = "navy"
  
  # Background gradient.
  # gradient_start = "DeepSkyBlue"
  # gradient_end = "SkyBlue"
  
  # Background image.
  # image = "background.jpg"  # Name of image in `static/img/`.
  # image_darken = 0.6  # Darken the image? Range 0-1 where 0 is transparent and 1 is opaque.

  # Text color (true=light or false=dark).
  # text_color_light = true  
  
[advanced]
 # Custom CSS. 
 css_style = ""
 
 # CSS class.
 css_class = ""
+++
```

importantly `page_type` should be set to `"talk"`.